# Display distinct data from column (and count) within SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have an issue with a trigger I am trying to create. I want the trigger to display an error message if the D_EMP_ID entries (for each individual ID) exceeds 9. in other words an employee with the ID of '1000' can have no more than 9 entries. If the tenth entry is added for '1000' it should display error.

But at the moment it doesn't show the error. whenever I add a new entry it gets added. Even if its the tenth, 11th, 12th etc.

Below is the code of the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_order_line_count
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON pl_work_allocation FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  order_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO order_count
   FROM pl_work_allocation WHERE d_emp_id = :new.d_emp_id;

  IF (order_count > 9) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Too many roles for ' || :new.d_emp_id || '');
  END IF;
END;
```

Below is the layout of the PL_WORK_ALLOCATION table:

```
S_REPORTED_CRIME_ID- D_EMP_ID-  WORK_DESC-  LEAD_POLICE_OFFICER-    WORK_START_DATE-   WORK_END_DATE-
12                   1000         example       1001                 08/26/2011         09/27/2012
15                   1010          test         1001                 08/26/2011         09/27/2012
1                    1000       Investigation   1003                 08/26/2011         08/26/2012
```

Comment: This looks like Oracle syntax so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: I have checked your trigger and it seems to work correct. May be this trigger is not enabled? Can you execute this please: ALTER TRIGGER tri_order_line_count ENABLE;

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43d71/1); doesn't even get a mutating table exception at run-time, with simple inserts. Are you sure the trigger was actually created, and is enabled?

Comment: @AlexPoole `doesn't even get a mutating table exception` This is the exceptional `before insert fore each row` trigger behavior, which, interestingly enough, is being mentioned only in 8i documentation and MOS. The `mutating table` exception will be immediately raised as soon as you decided to use `insert select` statement. As for OP, it would be better to reject the idea of placing that kind of checking in a trigger altogether - make a stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should add Rollback after raising error

```
if (order_count > 9)            
             then raise_application_error(-20001,
         'Too many roles for '|| :new.D_EMP_ID ||'' );
         ROLLBACK;
end if;
```

Comment: The `rollback` is after the `raise`, so it will never be reached. The data inserted into this table is rejected by the raise so there is nothing here to rollback. Other changes in the same transaction may or may not want to be rolled back, but that's up to the whatever is doing the insert/update, the trigger shouldn't decide that.

Comment: You can't use `rollback` or `commit` in a trigger